# How to select any element that has an attribute equal to red in css3?

Tags: css, css-selectors

If I want all `div`s that has attribute `data-color` equal to `red`, I can do

```css
div[data-color='red']
```

But what if I want any element at all, that has `data-color` equal to `red`?

How would I write that?

Comment: Just remove `div`.

Comment: So the css selector is just `[data-color='red']` ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use that same [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors), but without any element before attached to it

> Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and whose value
>   is exactly "value".

It will select any element with the `[data-color='red']`

**Note:**  even using the `''` (which is different than `""`),  it will **still** select `""` anyhow.

```css
[data-color='red'] {
  background: red;
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div data-color='red'>red</div>
<p data-color='red'>red</p>
<article data-color='red'>red</article>
<section data-color='red'>red</section>
<h1 data-color='red'>red</h1>
<span data-color='red'>red</span>

<hr />

<div data-color="red">red</div>
<p data-color="red">red</p>
<article data-color="red">red</article>
<section data-color="red">red</section>
<h1 data-color="red">red</h1>
<span data-color="red">red</span>
```

If you want to target a specific element you can just put that element before the attribute selector:

```css
div[data-color='red'] {
  background: red;
}
p[data-color='red'] {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div data-color='red'>red</div>
<p data-color='red'>red</p>
```

Comment: What difference does the single and double quote makes?

Comment: In this case, None, exactly none :)

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to just use:

```
[data-color='red']
```

or you could write it this way:

```
*[data-color='red']
```

you can also write it with double quotes, this will also select the same but it's worth keeping to the same format throughout your CSS file to maintain standards. I would recommend sticking to single quotes in this case.

```
[data-color="red"]
```

This would select any HTML element with the data-color attribute value equal to red.

For example:

```
<div data-color='red'>Red</div>
<p data-color='red'>Red</p>
<span data-color='red'>Red</span>
```

Working example:

```css
[data-color='red'] {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div data-color='red'>Red</div>
<p data-color='red'>Red</p>
<span data-color='red'>Red</span>
<hr data-color='red'/>
<section data-color='red'>Red</section>
<article data-color='red'>Red</article>
<aside data-color='red'>Red</aside>
```